# Another way to loop this for powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-active-directory

Could you please help me to loop this in a systematic manner. I cant think of anything better but I am sure there are many other ways to do this. When I look it like the following, I am having an error with two of the loops that have a star in the front. I am not having any error and it only displays the UPN and somehow does not work:

```
if (upnoption1RadioButton.Checked == true && specifiedCheckBox.Checked == false)
{

    UPN = firstName.ToLower() + "." + lastName.ToLower() + "@" + domain;

    string takeOne = "New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "" + UPN + "" -DisplayName "" + firstName + " " + lastName + "" -FirstName "" + firstName + "" -LastName "" + lastName + "" -UsageLocation "" + "NZ"" + " -LicenseAssignment "" + accountSkuId + ":" + license + "" -ForceChangePassword $False";

    powershellOutput = executeCommand.GetPowerShellInfo(takeOne, "Password");
}

else if (upoption2RadioButton.Checked == true && specifiedCheckBox.Checked == false)
{
    UPN = firstName.ToLower() + lastName.ToLower() + "@" + domain;

    string takeOne = "New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "" + UPN + "" -DisplayName "" + firstName + " " + lastName + "" -FirstName "" + firstName + "" -LastName "" + lastName + "" -UsageLocation "" + "NZ"" + " -LicenseAssignment "" + accountSkuId + ":" + license + "" -ForceChangePassword $False";

    powershellOutput = executeCommand.GetPowerShellInfo(takeOne, "Password");
}

else if ((selectedListValue == "DONOTASSIGNLICENSE") && (upnoption1RadioButton.Checked == true) && (specifiedCheckBox.Checked == true))
{
    UPN = firstName.ToLower() + "." + lastName.ToLower() + "@" + domain;
    string takeTwo = "New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "" + UPN + "" -DisplayName "" + firstName + " " + lastName + "" -FirstName "" + firstName + "" -LastName "" + lastName + "" -UsageLocation "" + "NZ"" + " -Password "" + passwordValue + "" -ForceChangePassword $False";

    powershellOutput = executeCommand.GetPowerShellInfo(takeTwo, "Password");

}

else if ((selectedListValue == "DONOTASSIGNLICENSE") && (upoption2RadioButton.Checked == true) && (specifiedCheckBox.Checked == true))
{
    UPN = firstName.ToLower() + lastName.ToLower() + "@" + domain;
    string takeTwo = "New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "" + UPN + "" -DisplayName "" + firstName + " " + lastName + "" -FirstName "" + firstName + "" -LastName "" + lastName + "" -UsageLocation "" + "NZ"" + " -Password "" + passwordValue + "" -ForceChangePassword $False";

    powershellOutput = executeCommand.GetPowerShellInfo(takeTwo, "Password");

}

****               else if ((selectedListValue == "DONOTASSIGNLICENSE") && (upnoption1RadioButton.Checked == true) && (specifiedCheckBox.Checked == false))
{
    UPN = firstName.ToLower() + "." + lastName.ToLower() + "@" + domain;
    string takeOne = "New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "" + UPN + "" -DisplayName "" + firstName + " " + lastName + "" -FirstName "" + firstName + "" -LastName "" + lastName + "" -UsageLocation "" + "NZ" -ForceChangePassword $False";

    powershellOutput = executeCommand.GetPowerShellInfo(takeOne, "Password");

}

****            else if ((selectedListValue == "DONOTASSIGNLICENSE") && (upoption2RadioButton.Checked == true) && (specifiedCheckBox.Checked == false))
{
    UPN = firstName.ToLower() + lastName.ToLower() + "@" + domain;
    string takeOne = "New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "" + UPN + "" -DisplayName "" + firstName + " " + lastName + "" -FirstName "" + firstName + "" -LastName "" + lastName + "" -UsageLocation "" + "NZ" -ForceChangePassword $False";

    powershellOutput = executeCommand.GetPowerShellInfo(takeOne, "Password");

}

else if (upnoption1RadioButton.Checked == true && specifiedCheckBox.Checked == true)
{
    UPN = firstName.ToLower() + "." + lastName.ToLower() + "@" + domain;

    string takeOne = "New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "" + UPN + "" -DisplayName "" + firstName + " " + lastName + "" -FirstName "" + firstName + "" -LastName "" + lastName + "" -UsageLocation "" + "NZ"" + " -LicenseAssignment "" + accountSkuId + ":" + license + "" -ForceChangePassword $False" + " -Password "" + passwordValue + """;


    powershellOutput = executeCommand.GetPowerShellInfo(takeOne, "Password");

}

else if (upoption2RadioButton.Checked == true && specifiedCheckBox.Checked == true)
{
    UPN = firstName.ToLower() + lastName.ToLower() + "@" + domain;

    string takeOne = "New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "" + UPN + "" -DisplayName "" + firstName + " " + lastName + "" -FirstName "" + firstName + "" -LastName "" + lastName + "" -UsageLocation "" + "NZ"" + " -LicenseAssignment "" + accountSkuId + ":" + license + "" -ForceChangePassword $False" + " -Password "" + passwordValue + """;

    powershellOutput = executeCommand.GetPowerShellInfo(takeOne, "Password");

}

outputTextBox.Text += UPN + ": " + powershellOutput;
Thread.Sleep(3000);

}
```

Some help here would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I what I mean is that I donot get any error and the powershell command does not work for those two loops but the other loops work fine.

Comment: powershellOutput = executeCommand.GetPowerShellInfo(takeOne, "Password"); this processes the powershell command the output would be the password.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I suggest debug your application to get the powershell command and try the command in your powershell tool to check whether the command is correct .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just pseudocode, but I believe you can replace that entire mess with this function:

```
private string PowershellOutput(string firstName, string lastName, string domain, string selectedListValue, string accountSkuId, string license, string passwordValue)
{
    string upn = firstName.ToLower() + (upnoption1RadioButton.Checked ? "." : "") + lastName.ToLower() + "@" + domain;

    string powershellCommand = string.Format(@"New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName ""{0}"" -DisplayName ""{1} {2}"" -FirstName ""{3}"" -LastName ""{4}"" -UsageLocation ""NZ"" -ForceChangePassword $False"
        + (selectedListValue != "DONOTASSIGNLICENSE" ? string.Format(@" -LicenseAssignment ""{0}:{1}""", accountSkuId, license) : " ")
        + (specifiedCheckBox.Checked ? string.Format(@" -Password ""{0}""", passwordValue) : "")
    , upn, firstName, lastName, firstName, lastName);

    return upn + ": " + executeCommand.GetPowerShellInfo(powershellCommand, "Password");
}
```

The string is the same for all instances, except whether or not to have the -Password or the -LicenseAssignment.  You do the LicenseAssignment when your selectedListValue != "DONOTASSIGNLICENSE", and you do the Password setting when specifiedCheckBox.Checked.

Also, the format of your UPN is the same for all of them, except for there being a dot or not, which is simply based on whether or not it's UPN1 or not.

Another note is that UPN has 2 options.  So it's either UPN1 or it isn't.  So you don't need to check if UPN2.  If it's not UPN1, then we know it's UPN2.  Don't over-optimize for the future.

**How I got to this**

What I did was organize your Conditionals.  There are three conditions.  DONOTASSIGNLICENSE, UPN1/UPN2, and "Specified".  I pretty much just re-wrote your conditions so all clauses had all conditions in the same order, then "Sort By Conditions" in my mind.  When it came out the other side, I could see the patterns of the texts, and that you were duplicating a lot of work.

Comment: You are also correct. I am duplicating a lot of stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @Nilay Can you select one answer as the answer, and/or up-vote mine and Pants' answers?

Answer (score 0):

After trying to comprehend your question it seems you want help with how your handling your if statements(?)

I'd suggest that you try using a Switch statement.

```
$a = 5
switch ($a) 
{ 
    1 {"The color is red."} 
    2 {"The color is blue."} 
    3 {"The color is green."} 
    4 {"The color is yellow."} 
    5 {"The color is orange."} 
    6 {"The color is purple."} 
    7 {"The color is pink."}
    8 {"The color is brown."} 
    default {"The color could not be determined."}
}
```

This would save space and make it more readable.

This is also just piece of sample code from [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx)